# How to include a program on startup?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to have an executable file run at startup, *Windows 7*.

I was wondering how I may do so directly at the command line or by way of batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows provides powershell to automatize this kind of tasks using "command prompt" or scripts.

In the case you are proposing, you can change the registry values that controls startup programs by using the new-item-property cmdlet like this

```
PS> New-ItemProperty HKM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\ -Name <pretty beautiful name for your app> -Value <executable for your app>
```

You can also use PowerShell to elliminate or to change keys. But, you know

> With big power comes great responsability

Answer (score -1):

On a windows comp
Hit the win + r
A small dialog box appears on bottom left. In the box type 
shell:startup
You are automatically redirected to the relevant folder. Just copy past ur program into this folder.

Answer (score -1):

If u have a more malicious intent in mind simply use the copy command to copy the file from its current destination(A USB perhaps) to the location gotten from the aforementioned method.
However there is a slight catch. This only works if ur the admin of the computer. So you would theoretically have to include code to hand your program admin access before copying the file
[Tutorial on how to do it here[1](http://www.hacking-tutorial.com/tips-and-trick/how-to-add-user-with-administrator-rights-using-command-prompt/)